# How to search by multiple ids?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I want to build a Symfony Query in which I find all the Users that already filled out a Poll.
First I get all PollResults from one Field in the Poll, so I don't have all the user-ids multiple times.
Then afterwards I want to find all Users which ids are in this collection of PollResults.
How can I do that? Here is the code that shows what I want to do:

```
$oneFieldsPollResults = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(PollResult::class)->findBy(['field' => $campaign->getOneFieldId()]);

$counting_users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findBy(/** The User-ID is in $oneFieldsPollResults */);
```

Answer (score 0):

get ids in oneFieldsPollResults and try :

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)->findBy(array('id' => $ids));
```